# How to set letters of an argument to lower case except capitalize the first letter?

Tags: expl3

I want to define a new command in which it is possible to accept an argument, then (regardless of cases of letters in the input), sets all letters to lower case except the first one

```
\documentclass{book}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\LowerCase}{m}
{
    \group_begin:
    \cs_set_protected:Npx \\ { \exp_not:o \\ }
    \text_lowercase:n {#1}
    \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
    \LowerCase{TestinG}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Search the documentation for titlecase

Answer (score 3):

From LaTeX 2022-11-01:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
    
\MakeTitlecase{TestinG}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Testing]

See [`ltnews36.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltnews36.pdf) for more information.

Comment: @JosephWright I'm usually using LuaLaTeX, so `\str_head:n` is a nice command and can mostly be used safely for strings. However, I've done a roleback to the version without unchanged first letter, because it seems to be the requested one.

Comment: Quite apart from the issue of 8-bit input, taking the head as a string would fail for with example a macro at the start of the input marking up some logical material, e.g. `\emph{text}`, which should come out as `\empt{Text}` not what you'd get ;)

Comment: @JosephWright That's why I wrote: "for strings". But no need to fight about not asked questions. So: Yes, you are right. It's better not to show the fragile addendum.

Answer (score 2):

There's already:

```
\documentclass{book}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\TitleCase}{m}
  {
    \text_titlecase:n {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\TitleCase{TestinG}

\end{document}
```